# Android: dload so file failed

Tags: dlopen

My app need load a library, but cannot load successfully, I got below error in applog file:

CrashException: dlopen failed: can't protect segments for "/xxx/xxx.so": Permission denied

Answer (score -1):

Possibly you are getting text relocation and avc denial error msg for this also, check in the log. Adding sepolicy rule for avc denial should solve your problem. But best practice will be to resolve the text relocation error in your code.